# How to add dependency in flink minikube cluster?

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-flink

I have a job jar which has dependency on flink-json-1.7.2.jar, flink-table_2.11-1.7.2.jar. This runs fine on my local machine if I add these two jars in lib folder of flink.
How can I achieve the same on my minikube cluster.
i.e. add the dependencies to flink.
Ps. I have setup my minikube by following [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html) documentation.

Also I can see those jars getting added in the fat jar created when I build the job jar.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Due to an issue in Apache Calcite, which prevents the user classloaders from being garbage-collected, we do not recommend building a fat-jar that includes the flink-table dependency. Instead, we recommend configuring Flink to include the flink-table dependency in the system classloader. This can be done by copying the flink-table.jar file from the ./opt folder to the ./lib folder.

FROM docs

Answer (score 0):

Since you have implemented Flink job on the local machine, I assume that it might be possible to create your own specific Docker image and include there requested *.jar files as described [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7/flink-container/docker/README.md). Although, you have already bootstrapped `minikube` Kubernetes cluster, customized Docker image can be used in the appropriate [Flink job](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7/flink-container/kubernetes/README.md#deploy-flink-job-cluster) Kubernetes deployment files as well.